Minimize the max value from a sum of sines
I'm considering functions of the form
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(t\right) =
\sin\left(\omega_1 t - \phi_1\right) +
\sin\left(\omega_2 t - \phi_2\right) + \cdots + \sin\left(\omega_n t - \phi_n\right)
$$

I was wondering if there was a way I could analytically ( or numerically ) determine what values of $\phi_j$ would make it so that the absolute maximum value of the $\operatorname{f}\left(t\right)$ is minimized, given all the values of $\omega_j\,?$.
For example, $\text{sin}(t)+\text{sin}(3t)$ has a lower maximum value than
$\sin\left(t\right) + \sin\left(3t-\pi\right)$.

I don't really know where to start with a problem like this, so any suggestions for where to explore would be greatly appreciated.
